# how to send email through amazon ses

Tags: amazon-ses, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer and nodemailer-ses-transport.

everytime I run my test code for send mail, I get an error message like this.

but I specified 'From' field in test I don't know why it won't recognize the field.

```
{ [InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'From'.]
message: 'Missing required header \'From\'.',
code: 'InvalidParameterValue',
time: Fri Apr 10 2015 01:34:36 GMT+0000 (UTC),
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 30 }
```

the test code is here.

please let me know wrong code.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var ses = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');

var sendAuthCode = function(gmail, message, callback) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(ses({
        accessKeyId : MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey : MY_SECRET_ACEESS_KEY,
        region : "us-west-2",
        rateLimit : 1
    }));

    transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'mail bot',
        to: gmail,
        subject: 'TEST',
        text: message
    }, function(err, resStatus) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback('success');
        }
    });
}

sendAuthCode("some@gmail.com", "hello", function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

UPDATED
I solved the problem!!
problem was that amazon ses can only send mail between verified email address.
if you want send an email to user who not verified,
you should request to increase ses limit on ses dashboard.

anyway thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "mail bot" as sender. Use legitimate email.